# Create bitmap from canvas specified area

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, crop

I'm building my own image crop. What I have is a custom view that takes the whole width and height of the screen. I'm setting a drawable image as a background of the custom view in the XML, so it's the background of the views' canvas. Now I'm trying to create a bitmap from a specified area on the canvas to get the part of the canvas background which is in the specified area. 
The custom view in the xml file:

```
<com.imout.customviews.CropZone
     android:id="@+id/croppedZone"
     android:background="@drawable/profil"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

First I build the whole canvas bitmap as below:

```
canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mScreenHeight, mScreenWidth,Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
```

Then I'm trying to get the selected area as below:

```
Bitmap selectedRectangle = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvasBitmap,mImagePosition.left, mImagePosition.top,mImageWidth,mImageHeight);
```

But the problem is that when I'm placing the **selectedRectangle** bitmap as a source of an ImageView, I get a black filled ImageView...

Could someone help me out with that ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: canvasBitmap looks empty to me. Can you post more code?

Comment: I've updated the code by putting the xml code of the custom view. Maybe I'm wrong but if I set the background of the custom view in xml, it's the background of the canvas associated to the view right ?

Comment: it is definitely possible. Still, your `canvasBitmap` is an empty bitmap of size `mScreenHeight, mScreenWidth`.